# In Subsite, i click to Title or description, or Logo and occur a error "Something went wrong"

Tags: site-settings, site-logo

In Subsite, 
i click to Title or description, or Logo 
the URL : https://domain.com/sites/ABC/SUBSITE1/SITESITE2/_layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx

and occur a error as below

"A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this web site.  Please choose another title."

i try other page in site setting such as AreaWelcomePage.aspx that is fine.
so only the prjsetng.aspx occur error.

how can i fix it.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution from john

1. Browse to Site Content and see if the Site Assets library exists. If
   it does, delete it.
2. If you don’t see it there, open the site in SharePoint Designer and
   select All Files.
3. See if the Site Assets library is there. If it is, delete it. (I did
   find it there in my case).
4. Now go back to your site and go to Site Settings then Title,
   Description, and Logo.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/johnmhester.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/error-changing-a-site-title-in-sharepoint-2013/amp/?client=safari